# 行列の逆行列が計算できない（Rの系統樹の処理）

Tags: r

系統樹は自分で以下のように作成しています。
どうやってもエラーが解消されなくて困っています。作成方法がいけないのでしょうか？？

```
> newick_tree<-"(A:4,(B:2,(C:2.953469601,D:1.443532938):1.136357167):1.104667235);"
> phylo_tree <- read.tree(text = newick_tree)
> vcv(phylo_tree)
  A        B        C        D
A 4 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
B 0 3.104667 1.104667 1.104667
C 0 1.104667 5.194494 2.241024
D 0 1.104667 2.241024 3.684557
>  gls.ancova(log_lifespan ~ body_size, vcv(phylo_tree), Model, Model_I)
Error in solve.default(Sigma) : 
  Lapack routine dgesv: system is exactly singular: U[1,1] = 0
```

Comment: `evomap` パッケージのインストール方法(CRAN には登録されていないので `devtools` で GitHub のリポジトリからになるでしょう)と、`Model` と `Model_I` の作成手順を示してもらわないと、誰も回答はできないでしょう。

Comment: と思ったら、[vcv(phylogenetic_tree) cannot be solved !](https://community.rstudio.com/t/vcv-phylogenetic-tree-cannot-be-solved/177383)で回答が付きましたね。